# Creating Add-on for Firefox using XPCOM and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, xpcom

Need to create a plugin for Firefox using XPCOM and JavaScript. I am getting error like "Components not registered"

Refereed the following link

[Help me create a Firefox extension (Javascript XPCOM Component)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834669/help-me-create-a-firefox-extension-javascript-xpcom-component?rq=1)

He says it is working fine for him. If someone provide a sample Application for the same , It will be more helpful.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly decent tutorial [here](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/)

Comment: Thank you very much .The link which you have provided is for creating Extension for Firefox. I need to create a plugin for Firefox.It will be more helpful if you provide me an option to create a plug-in without using C++